# how to select/view specific row in BigQuery to troubleshoot?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I'm a rank beginner with BigQuery, but I have a Google Apps Script to load data from a BQ table to a Google Sheet that's been working fine for years until now.

Now I'm getting this error:

> API call to bigquery.jobs.getQueryResults failed with error: Error while reading table: >inventory.all_sports.qty_sold_archive, error message: Could not convert value to integer. Row 136884; Col 2

I've been looking in the BigQuery console to try to view that row so I can try to fix the problem, but can't figure out how to do that first step.

Is there a way to Select a specific row from BQ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SAFE_CAST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#safe_casting) to try to cast values to integer and then find those which could not be converted by checking for NULLs:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT value, SAFE_CAST(value AS INT64) AS converted
  FROM table
)
WHERE converted IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks!

I tried your command and still got an error:

Error while reading table: (table), error message: Could not convert value to integer. Row 109428; Col 2.

FWIW, I realized that the table is tied to a Google Sheet, and I found out that the problem was that there was some text in a column that should be a number. So I was able to fix it on the GS.

But I'm still curious if there's a way to "select record 109428" or something like that for future reference.